# 10 Dogs and 4 Cats. Possibilities for a sequence with 2 dogs and 1 cat.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a sequence of 3, I think that there are (10*9) ways to have two dogs and (4) ways for there to be one cat in a set, so there are (10*9)(4)= 360 ways to have this sequence of three.

However, I need to find the number of sequences with two dogs and one cat where the cat must be in the middle of the two dogs.

Comment: There are $\binom{10}{2}=\frac{10\cdot 9}{2}$ ways to **choose** $2$ dogs, so answer to first is $180$, not $360$. For the second question, in a set nobody is in the middle. Do you mean **sequences** of choices with the cat in the middle?

Comment: yes, thats what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Does order matter?  Is dog1,dog2,cat3 different from dog2,dog1,cat3?  Usually in a set it does not.  Then you have double counted all the pairs of dogs and need to divide by $2$

For the second question, it appears order does matter.  Now your original count is correct-you have $10$ choices for the dog on the left, $4$ for the cat, and $9$ for the dog on the right.  There would be more choices if the cat were free to be in any position but order mattered.